# gpg.exe is not decrypting file in the ssis package after creating a job

Tags: ssis, jobs

I have inserted an execute process task in the control flow of the SSIS package which gets encrypted files from a folder and decrypts file using the gpg.exe. I have passed the key as well as passphrase in to the expression of the execute process task. while running the package directly it executes successfully and also decrypts the file. But, when i create a job in the sql server 2005 of that package and execute the job, it shows successfully executed but neither of the file is being converted.

Any suggestion what's going wrong or any other security issues is existing in the job.
I have spent good amount of time on googling over it but could not found solution.

Comment: You have a permissions problem.

Comment: where is the permission issues? where i need to modify the permisssion?

Comment: The identity the job is running as has no permissions. You need to set the right user identity for the job or job step.

Comment: @Ben I have given all the permission to the user which executes the job

Comment: Amish, have you set the "run as user name" on the SqlAgent Job step?

Comment: @Ben, I think Run as User name is not there while starting job at step 1, Although i've staretd sql by running as administrator and logged in user have all the permission.

Comment: Have you got the SQLAgent Proxy Account set up?

Comment: Yes @Ben I have tried the same also, But still have the same problem.

Comment: Configuration problem, belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, There is no error in the package or job. It was only a security issue which was not allowing to execute a job containing executable file. What i did that i have added the current user detail in sql server configuration manager>>SQL server agent.
Instead of Built in account check the This account and enter the current account detail.